# combine grep and grep -v search together

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to combine `grep` and `grep -v` search together.
Output should be display all lines ending with `.xml`, but to exclude lines starting with `$`.

Here are the commands I have tried; none worked:

- ```
  grep *.xml file1.txt | grep -v '$' file1.txt > output
  ```
- ```
  grep *.xml | grep -v '$' file1.txt > output
  ```
- ```
  grep *.xml grep -v '$' file1.txt > output
  ```
- ```
  grep *.xml '$' file1.txt > output
  ```

Answer (score 8):

To match a `$` at the start of a line, anchor it to the start of the line with `^`.  Also, `$` by itself matches the end of the line (it's a special character, just like `^`), and `*` will not do what you think it does (it works differently in regular expressions compared to in shell globbing patterns).  So,

```
grep -v '^\$'
```

will filter out all lines starting with a `$`.

You can do either

```
grep '\.xml$' file1.txt | grep -v '^\$'
```

or

```
grep '^[^$].*\.xml$' file1.txt
```

to find all lines in the file `file1.txt` that do not start with `$` but that ends with `.xml`.

Notice that I also escape the dot in `.xml` as that otherwise matches any character, and that the second command combines both criteria by using a character range (`[ ... ]`) containing all characters except `$` (the `.*` matches any number of any characters).

The single quotes are necessary so that the shell won't interpret the regular expression as a shell globbing pattern.

Comment: Is there also a more general approach? Can you combine `grep` and `grep -v` when it comes to _words_ instead of single characters?

Comment: @axm__ The user use-case was to remove lines starting with a single dollar sign, but the expression used can obviously be arbitrarily complex.

Comment: I understand. Your answer has already been useful to me and indeed answers the question. However, since this question comes up really high when you google 'combining `grep` and `grep -v`, I hoped that you or  someone else could  elaborate on more general use cases. Especially "non-fixed" pattern which are really easy to do with piping from grep to grep (`grep 'i want this' | grep -v 'but not this'`). But if a separate question might be better, I'll consider that :)

Comment: found simple alternative with `awk` for more general purpose :  `awk '/find this/ && !/but not this/'`

Answer (score -1):

You should use "cat" command to direct the output to an file.

And then use regular expression to filter the keyword, in this case all lines start with $ symbol is '^[$]'.

So you can use command `cat *.xml | grep -v '^[$]'`.

Comment: You don't need `cat` for this. Use `grep -v '^[$]' *.xml`. Plus the op asked for lines ending with `.xml`.